# MongoDB returns empty result on a huge dataset

Tags: json, mongodb, indexing

I'm running a MongoDB 3.1 server with ~160 million documents in a collection. A document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "123456789" },
  "lastChange": "2015-02-09 13:22:27",
  "startDate": "2015-02-09",
  "receiptNumber" : 296,
  "itemReceiptPositions": [
    {
        "itemId": 900064,
        "listPrice": 8.99
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created the index on "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" and "receiptNumber":

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "receiptNumber" : 1
  },
  "name" : "receiptNumber_1",
  "ns" : "someDatabase.someCollection"
},

{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" : 1
  },
  "name" : "itemReceiptPositions.itemId_1",
  "ns" : "someDatabase.someCollection"
}
```

When I search for this particular document via the itemReceiptPositions.itemId key, MongoDB cannot find the document:

```
> db.someCollection.find( { "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" : 900064 }).count()
0
```

But whenever I search for the key "receiptNumber", the document is found! Even the query

```
> db.someCollection.find( { "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" : { "$gt" : 0 }}).count()
```

returns zero results. How can this be?

Here are the .explain() outputs of both queries:

```
> db.someCollection.find( { "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" : 900064 } ).explain()
{
  "queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "someDatabase.someCollection",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
      "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" : {
        "$eq" : 900064
      }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "FETCH",
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
          "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "itemReceiptPositions.itemId_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
          "itemReceiptPositions.itemId" : [
            "[900064.0, 900064.0]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
  },
  "serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "someHost",
    "port" : 1234,
    "version" : "3.1.0-pre-",
    "gitVersion" : "bbd95ca6a8b538b4cffece0b9d9c3ed811a455a7"
  },
  "ok" : 1
}
```

and

```
> db.someCollection.find( { "receiptNumber" : 296 }).explain()
{
  "queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "someDatabase.someCollection",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
      "receiptNumber" : {
        "$eq" : 296
      }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "FETCH",
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
          "receiptNumber" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "receiptNumber_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
          "receiptNumber" : [
            "[296.0, 296.0]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
  },
  "serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "someHost",
    "port" : 1234,
    "version" : "3.1.0-pre-",
    "gitVersion" : "bbd95ca6a8b538b4cffece0b9d9c3ed811a455a7"
  },
  "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the query operator [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

```
db.someCollection.find( { "itemReceiptPositions" : {$elemMatch: {"itemId" : 900064}}})
```

Comment: You do? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @ZeMoon: thanks, but this doesn't solve it :( It still doesn't find any document.

Answer (score 0):

AH! Spotted it!

You've mistakenly capitalized an E and also added an extra p in there, check your explain query:

```
db.someCollection.find( { "itemREceiptPopsitions.itemId" : 900064 } ).explain()

itemREceiptPopsitions...
     ^       ^
```

You probably made this mistake in your original query too

As a side note, your query works fine, I checked in try.mongodb.org, see for yourself:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but that's a typing error I did while typing the query in StackOverflow. I didn't copy & paste the actual query I ran against the database. I double checked the query I ran against MongoDB and it doesn't have typing errors. But thanks for the hint ;)

/Edit: Did you indexed the itemId?

Comment: nope, the mongodb fiddle won't let you create indexes as far as I know. I doubt the index is creating any issues though.

Comment: It could be a corrupted index. Can you try the query with `.hint({ "$natural" : 1 })` to force a tablescan?